# Magento 2 Won't install on AMPPS

Tags: magento2, php-5.6

I'm trying to install Magento 2 on AMPPS locally, I read the requirement [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html) ,All the requirement is installed but Magento installer still give me an error without details :

[image]

**Environment :**

PHP 5.6.11
MySQL 5.6.25
Apache 2.4.12

I checked all the required PHP extensions in phpinfo(), All is enabled.

I do not know what can I do more .. I restart/reinstall the AMPPS, I clear the browser history .. nothing change !

Comment: Do you try to add phpinfo(); to setup/index.php to verify that all settings/modules is applied?

Comment: Why not use php7? It is easy to change in ampps

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your PHP version and required PHP version are empty in your case. That could mean that they cannot be defined.
Try to debug the code in \Magento\Setup\Model\PhpReadinessCheck::checkPhpVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ampps **control panel**, select **PHP**, click on **Php Extension** and enable the following extensions:

> ```
> bz2.so
> ctype.so
> curl.so
> gd.so
> iconv.so
> intl.so
> mbstring.so
> mcrypt.so
> mongo.so
> mysql.so
> mysqli.so
> openssl.so
> pdo_mysql.so
> pdo_sqlite.so
> soap.so
> sockets.so
> sqlite3.so
> xsl.so
> zip.so
> zlib.so
> ```

Alternatively you can [clone the Magento repository](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html), after that if you try to install Magento you can see which extension are missing.

Answer (score 0):

AMPPS default is not install ctype extension and Magento 2 need this extension to check.
You need open AMPPS application -> Open PHP tab -> PHP extension. Choose ctype.so and click 'Apply' button. Restart Apache and you can Readiness Check

Hope it help!